# JQL - Look at issues created the last 13 months

Tags: reporting, jql

I am trying to figure out how to filter issues created last 13 months so that I can have a constant overview.

The report I want to make will look something like this:
[Report layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbs9G.png)

My issue is that I only know about the "startofweek/endofweek" kind of JQL *( created > startOfWeek("-1") and created <= endOfWeek(-1) )*. Is it possible to write something similar containing last 13 months?

I am not sure on how to write a suitable JQL for this. I am also fairly new to JQL and SQL* (general knowledge)*.